# Change value in grouping based on condition

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I'm starting with the following data:

```
df <- data.frame(Person=c("Ada","Ada","Bob","Bob","Carl","Carl"), Day=c(1,2,2,1,1,2), Fruit=c("Apple","X","Apple","X","X","Orange"))

  Person Day  Fruit
1    Ada   1  Apple
2    Ada   2      X
3    Bob   2  Apple
4    Bob   1      X
5   Carl   1      X
6   Carl   2 Orange
```

And I want to loop through every person and replace the unknown fruit `X` with either `Apple` or `Orange` while making sure that if it's `Orange` one day, it should be `Apple` the next day, and vice versa.

For Ada: `Day 1 = Apple`, meaning `Day 2 = X <- Orange`

I don't know where to start other than:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
      group_by(Person)
```

- any suggestions for direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one idea using `case_when` to check if each group already has "Apple" or "Orange", and then assign the opposite value if Fruit is "X".

Notice that I added `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` when creating the example data frame, which aims to avoid the creation of factor columns.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  group_by(Person) %>%
  mutate(Fruit = case_when(
    Fruit %in% "X" & any(Fruit %in% "Apple")  ~ "Orange",
    Fruit %in% "X" & any(Fruit %in% "Orange") ~ "Apple",
    TRUE                                      ~ Fruit
  )) %>%
  ungroup()   

# # A tibble: 6 x 3
#   Person   Day Fruit 
#   <chr>  <dbl> <chr> 
# 1 Ada     1.00 Apple 
# 2 Ada     2.00 Orange
# 3 Bob     2.00 Apple 
# 4 Bob     1.00 Orange
# 5 Carl    1.00 Apple 
# 6 Carl    2.00 Orange
```

**DATA**

```
df <- data.frame(Person=c("Ada","Ada","Bob","Bob","Carl","Carl"), 
                 Day=c(1,2,2,1,1,2), 
                 Fruit=c("Apple","X","Apple","X","X","Orange"),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: Thanks, I like this approach! Although for some reason I can't reproduce your results; "Carl" gets oranges on both days.

Comment: Try to find what is the difference between the example dataset and the real-world dataset.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution using `case_when` from `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

# Changing datatypes to character instead of factor
df[] <- lapply(df, as.character)

# Optional, but this line will convert all columns to appropriate datatype, eg. Day will be integer
df <- readr::type_convert(df)

df %>%
  group_by(Person) %>%
  mutate(
    Contains_Apple = any(Fruit == "Apple"),
    Contains_Orange = any(Fruit == "Orange"),
    Fruit = case_when(
      Fruit == "X" & Contains_Apple == F ~ "Apple",
      Fruit == "X" & Contains_Orange == F ~ "Orange",
      TRUE ~ Fruit
    )
  )

# A tibble: 6 x 5
# Groups: Person [3]
  Person   Day Fruit  Contains_Apple Contains_Orange
  <chr>  <int> <chr>  <lgl>          <lgl>          
1 Ada        1 Apple  T              F              
2 Ada        2 Orange T              F              
3 Bob        2 Apple  T              F              
4 Bob        1 Orange T              F              
5 Carl       1 Apple  F              T              
6 Carl       2 Orange F              T
```

Remove the `Contains_Apple` and `Contains_Orange` by:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(Person) %>% 
  mutate(Contains_Apple = any(Fruit == "Apple"),
         Contains_Orange = any(Fruit == "Orange"),
         Fruit = case_when(Fruit == "X" & Contains_Apple == F ~ "Apple",
                           Fruit == "X" & Contains_Orange == F ~ "Orange",
                           TRUE ~ Fruit)) %>% 
  select(Person, Day, Fruit) %>% 
  ungroup()

# A tibble: 6 x 3
  Person   Day Fruit 
  <chr>  <int> <chr> 
1 Ada        1 Apple 
2 Ada        2 Orange
3 Bob        2 Apple 
4 Bob        1 Orange
5 Carl       1 Apple 
6 Carl       2 Orange
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I can't reproduce your results (and I'm beginning to think there is something wrong on my end, becasue I had the same reproducability issue with another reply).
The first three columns remain unchanged and the two new columns "Contains_..." are filled with TRUE values.

Comment: Hm, I have no idea what could be causing the issue. When in doubt, restart the R session and run the code again. Otherwise, maybe update `dplyr` if you can? Also, try updating your question with the code you are using that gives you this result. I'll see if I experience the same issue.

Comment: A simple restart actually did the trick, thanks! Works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

Simple with looping:

```
fruity_loop <- function(frame) { 
    ops <- c('Apple', 'Orange')
    for(x in 1:nrow(frame)) {
    if(frame[x,]['Fruit'] == 'X') { 
      if(frame[x-1,]['Fruit'] == ops[1]) { frame[x,]['Fruit'] <- ops[2] } else { frame[x,]['Fruit'] <- ops[1] } } 
    }
    return(frame)
}
```

Example:

```
fruity_loop(df)
```

[image]